# Intellij/Gradle sync fails behind Corporate proxy

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, truststore, zscaler

I am behind a corporate firewall (Zscaler) which rewrites TLS traffic with its own certs.

When I try to create a Gradle project in intellij, I receive the following error, even after importing the CA and intermediate certs into both Intellij (via the `Server Certificates` settings page) and into every Java trust store I can think of.

```
Sync Failed
Download https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-bin.zip   797ms
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I even imported them into Intellij's private JRE e.g.

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\keytool.exe -importcert -alias zscaler_root_ca     -keystore C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file zscaler_root_ca.crt
C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\keytool.exe -importcert -alias zscaler_root_ca     -keystore C:\Progra~1\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file zscaler_root_ca.crt
"C:\Users\jonathan.bates\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\173.4301.25\jre64\bin\keytool.exe" -importcert -alias zscaler_root_ca     -keystore "C:\Users\jonathan.bates\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\173.4301.25\jre64\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit -file zscaler_root_ca.crt
```

Do I need to be doing anything else?

Comment: I'd (also) ask corporate IT staff to help with this as they caused the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, they aren't java/gradle devs, and in my field, the proxy is non-negotiable

Comment: At least make the issue transparent so that they know how much harm the proxy causes.

Comment: Double check you are using the correct JRE were you ahave added that proxy certificate (in About dialog) and that this certificate is indeed exists (`keytool -list ...`). Try enabling **Accept non-trusted certificates automatically** option in Settings | Tools | Server Certificates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The corporate issued certificate needs to be included in the truststore used by Gradle. Troubleshooting this can be difficult, especially if you have multiple versions of Java and the JRE installed. The first thing to determine is what JRE Gradle is using. There is an answer that points out the issue is resolved by using Gradle Wrapper. The [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) calls the project specific Java environment which is defined in gradle.properties. By default, it is set to `distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME`. To get Gradle to build with untrusted certificates one can follow the [instructions in the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.caching.http.HttpBuildCache.html#N1D7DE):

> The SSL certificate for the HTTP build cache backend may be untrusted since it is internally provisioned or a self-signed certificate.
>
> In such a scenario, you can either configure the build JVM environment to trust the certificate, or set this property to true to disable verification of the server's identity.
>
> Allowing communication with untrusted servers keeps data encrypted during transmission, but makes it easier for a man-in-the-middle to impersonate the intended server and capture data.

It is better to import the cert into the JVM used by Gradle which looks like what you were trying to do. If you want IntelliJ to know about the corporate certificate you can import those via the UI by Navigating to Settings > Tools > Server Certificates. Import the certificate file issued by your organization and retry the build.

Comment: Yeah - I was new to JVM when I answered my question, and the answer was junk.  I'll remove it.  It was indeed just the JRE not having the correct certs in its trust store.  It was a long time ago . now, but my guess is that I was just importing into the wrong JRE

Comment: Gradle had just stopped working for some reason for me. Switching from `'wrapper' task in Gradle build script` to `gradle-wrapper.properties file` in the `Use Gradle from:` dropdown worked, I believe for the reasons you mentioned. Not sure if it had gotten switched at some point, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

#### The Fix: Put the ZScaler Root Cert into IJ

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Go to settings -> Security -> Manage Certificates
3. Go to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" tab
4. Scroll down to the item "ZScaler Root CA" - being a "Z" word it'll probably be near or at the bottom of the list
5. Hit "Export..."
6. Follow the steps of the Wizard to export your certificate as a .CER file & save it to somewhere on your machine
7. Now open IntelliJ (IJ)
8. Open settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
9. Search for "cert" to filter settings and go to "Server Certificates"
10. Click on the little + icon
11. Browse to the file you just saved and hit OK & OK again on settings

That should do it.

**Note:** the assumption is that you use Google Chrome the ZScaler root certificate is already stored in Chrome's trust store. If that's not the case for you, hopefully you will find another way to get the ZScaler Root cert. Worst case scenario: you could always ask your IT dept. who I'm sure are the ones managing ZScaler and should know how to get you the cert.

#### The More Detailed Discussion

This seems to be a general problem with IntelliJ (IJ), not just for a Gradle task but when IJ tries to connect to any HTTPS site, as pointed out by the comment of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371045/jon-bates):

> intellij uses a different secret store to your terminal.

Expanding on that comment, we note from the [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-server-certificates.html):

> IntelliJ IDEA provides its own storage for trusted certificates.

Now, from that JetBrains doc and from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60071113/5134722), one approach that would work  is to simply accept all non-trusted certificates automatically. To understand why this is an OK approach, we recall that the whole problem was created in the first place by being behind ZScaler. Since you're behind ZScaler, you can trust that the ZScaler intermediate server that intercepts all your requests will block any untrustworthy sites for you, so you don't need to worry about it in IJ. Put another way, by the time ZScaler has forwarded those certs to IJ, you can already trust them.

However, the problem with that approach arises when your organisation has allowed you to disable ZScaler. In this case, if you disable ZScaler, then you are no longer protected by it. And when you do so, are you going to remember to revert your IJ settings? Maybe, but it would be an awful manual burden to do so. And more likely, you probably won't remember and then there's the possibility that your IJ can connect to untrustworthy sites. I don't know the full security details, so maybe there are some other measures taken to mitigate against such a vulnerability, but at the face of it this seems to me like a vulnerability. For example, an attacker could set up a fake update site for updating one of your IntelliJ plugins and install a malicious plugin instead, without you even knowing. And now you've effectively got a virus on your machine, because whenever you run IJ, the plugin runs too, and can probably do all sorts of bad stuff.

So a safer approach is to get to the root of the problem, literally: find the ZScaler root certificate and add that to the IJ trust store. Then IJ can trust that cert, and any downstream certs that ZScaler issues when intercepting your traffic.

#### Why the Root Certificate?

It's worth mentioning that the root certificate you add is not the same as the certificate that IJ warns you about when you suffer a problem. E.g. when I tried "check for updates" the cert that was causing the issue was issued to "*.google.com". I believe these are just the interceptor certs that ZScaler creates when it intercepts your traffic. The real cert for Google is used by ZScaler to communicate with Google. The "proxy" cert is the one that ZScaler generates to talk to your machine. Since ZScaler has to generate such a proxy cert for all imaginable sites, it's not enough to just add them to your trust store in IJ. Not only that, but these proxy certs appear to have pretty short shelf lives - the one I saw expired in two weeks. So you'd have to just keep re-adding them to the IJ trust store. And the IJ trust store would then just get cluttered up with all these temporary certs created by ZScaler. That's why you want to add the root cert. I believe it acts as the ultimate signing authority for any of those temporary proxy certs that are handed out. And the one I see doesn't expire for over 20 years. So I don't see myself having to fiddle with that IJ setting again for another while yet.

#### Notes

In essence, the fix given in this answer is effectively the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976050/5134722), but I am expanding on how to actually get the ZScaler cert from Google Chrome settings, and I give some discussion about why we're doing what we're doing, and comparison to alternatives.

Comment: This worked for me except the Zscaler cert was under "Trusted Publishers". Not sure what the differences are  but in case anyone else can't find it, there ya go.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly it can be related to certificate. To verify this, removing the option  `accepted certificates` and checking "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically" may solves the issue. As @Colm Bhandal commented, it is not a solution , but a workaround solution.

[image]

Comment: This is a bit of a dangerous approach, if you are allowed to disconnect your VPN (as we are). It would allow an on-path attacker to attack you as soon as you disconnect the VPN. You really only want to trust the ZScaler root cert.

Comment: Yes.. Fully agree. Added more description related to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I updated the setting to `Auto Import Certificate` and it worked for me

```
Settings -> Tools -> Server Certificates -> Check the box for auto import
```

Comment: I don't see a setting named that. Do you mean "Accept non-trusted certificates automatically?"

Comment: When you select  'Server Certificates' then  it's at the top of the popup window

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to be doing anything else?

Yes, probably. `JAVA_HOME` is a variable Gradle looks at to choose the Java to execute it.
Once you have Java with its trust store containing the required certs, try setting `JAVA_HOME` to that dir.

Answer (score 0):

For me, every setting seemed correct, that mentioned above to check.
I do not have a clue why, but the error message: `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` disappeared and `gradle build` started working after upgrading the Gradle Wrapper of the project:
https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

The key action was to run `gradlew.bat` in the Terminal tab.

Comment: This is because intellij uses a different secret store to your terminal.  If you run `gradlew build` from the terminal, and the certs are installed, gradle will pull the dependencies it needs, and cache them.  When you run subsequently from intellij, it has everything it needs, and will be able to build form the local cache